# Difference between Matlab versions

Tags: matlab

I have been implementing this paper:

http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610918.2011.575506#.UrijOLS_UhI

I can send a copy should anybody require it.

I think that my implementation is correct but I get significantly different answers to those given in the paper:

My results
     B0 0.0470
     B1 2.1635
     B2 1.1560
     B3 0.7451
     B4 0.4931

Results in paper
     B0 0.1228
     B1 2.1630
     B2 1.1552
     B3 0.7444
     B4 0.4922

As you can see B0 is way off while the remaining Beta values are only correct to decimal places which is not good enough. Could the difference be done to differences in the versions of Matlab used? I use R2011a where as the author uses Matlab 7.0?

```
function [b_LRRE]=LRRE(y,x)

[n, p]=size(x);

dim=1;

b=x\y;

sig_ols_sq=((y-x*b)'*(y-x*b))/(n-p);



econFlag=0;
[U,sigma,V] = svd(x,econFlag);



d=zeros(p,1);
d=diag(d);


alpha=V'*b;
Delta=sigma.^2;
I=ones(p,1);
I=diag(I);


for jj=1:50


for ii=1:p

d(ii,ii)=(Delta(ii,ii)*(alpha(ii)^2-sig_ols_sq))/(sig_ols_sq+Delta(ii,ii)*alpha(ii)^2);


end

A=pinv(Delta+I)*(Delta+d);
b_LRRE=V*A*V'*b;

alpha=V'*b_LRRE;

end


end
```

Here is the data

```
 78.5   1   7   26  6   60
 74.3   1   1   29  15  52
 104.3  1   11  56  8   20
 87.6   1   11  31  8   47
 95.9   1   7   52  6   33
 109.2  1   11  55  9   22
 102.7  1   3   71  17  6
 72.5   1   1   31  22  44
 93.1   1   2   54  18  22
 115.9  1   21  47  4   26
 83.8   1   1   40  23  34
 113.3  1   11  66  9   12
 109.4  1   10  68  8   12
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off contacting the authors of the paper.

Comment: Absolutely agree with Ismail Badawi. I would take possible discrepancies to the author rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: If there is possibility then try your code with matlab 7.0. I experienced similar thing while working with a study project.